# How to reset transactions? I can't move funds

Tags: transactions

I tried some transactions and they are still unfinished. I started them on the 22nd of may and since then it has been a nightmare.

I could only succeed doing 1 transaction but now I can't do more. They always fail even if I try with high gas.

What can I do?

I tried this:

https://kb.myetherwallet.com/transactions/check-status-of-ethereum-transaction.html

But it is not found, no matter what network I use.

What the hell can I do?

Answer (score 0):

From [this post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/33089/how-can-a-transaction-fail)  on what causes a transaction to fail. It seems like you have covered two of the steps(I take it you mean higher gas as higher limit and price)

A contract call must be throwing or the above statement is untrue.

Comment: I think I beggin to understand what happened. I tried to move 0.35 eth and failed, then I successfully made another transaction and the account was down to 0.32 eth. Now the funds are blocked since the original transaction  tried to move a higher number than I actually have in the account now. I am depositing more funds to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Simply adding more funds solved the problem, old transactions finished and now it works well.

Answer (score 0):

You cant reset the transaction, but you can override the transaction, which is in pending state for the very long time.
To override the transaction, send the 0 ether to the same account, to which you sent earlier, with higher gas than before, So it will override the transaction and cancel the previous one.